# Python format function

Tags: python, string, format

I have a value formatter

```
def formatter(value):
    return '{:.8f}'.format(value)
```

but instead of always returning to 8 decimal places I want to return to max of 8 decimal places so.

```
input                 |     desired_output
100                   |          100
100.01                |         100.01
3.1232342341312323434 |       3.12323423
```

How do I do that?
this is for applying to a large array of numbers. That then gets sucked up into a sql server at the moment the numbers keep overflowing the limits that the dba has set.

thanks

Comment: `round(3.1232342341312323434, 8)` might be more suitable for rounding floating point numbers for passing to a fixed precision numeric.

Comment: Dear KillerSnail, did my solution helped solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering your question:**

Just use float presentation type `'{:g}'` instead `'{:f}'` as described in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). This discards trailing zeros automatically. Additionally it switches to exponential notation if required.

```
def formatter(value):
    return "{:^14.8g}".format(value)

l = [100, 100.01, 3.1232342341312323434,
     0.000000000000123, 1234567899.999]

for x in l:
    print(formatter(x))
```

Output:

```
     100      
    100.01    
  3.1232342   
   1.23e-13   
1.2345679e+09
```

---

**Some probably useful extension of your formatter function**

Changing the formatter function a little to allow you to set precision and width of the printed field when calling it:

```
def formatter(value, precision, width):
    return "{{:^{}.{}g}}".format(width, precision).format(value)

l = [100, 100.01, 3.1232342341312323434,
     0.000000000000123, 1234567899.999]

for x in l:
    print(formatter(x, 5, 20))
```

Output:

```
             100              
            100.01            
            3.1232            
           1.23e-13           
          1.2346e+09
```

I found the nested format() function on this page about [Pandas Formatting Snippets](https://blog.henryhhammond.com/pandas-formatting-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
'{:^<stringwidth>.8f}'.format(value).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

where stringwidth is the width of your desired output wherein the value should be centered.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution doesn't work if the `stringwidth` is greater than the number of characters that makes your numbers, because it adds spaces around the string and the `rstrip` doesn't have any effect.

For it to work, first you should round it (and strip, if necessary), and then, as the second step - center it. Thus, we have:

```
numbers = [100, 100.01, 3.1232342341312323434]

for number in numbers:
    rounded_number = '{:.8f}'.format(i).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    centered_number = '{:^14}'.format(rounded_number)  # substitute 14 with the desired width
    print (centered_number)

    # Or, as a one-liner
    # print ('{:^14}'.format('{:.8f}'.format(i).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')))
```

Output:

```
     100      
    100.01    
  3.12323423
```